# Style with Converter in other assembly

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class library which contains a `ResourceDictionary` that holds some `Styles`.
The dictionary references a `Converter`, that's defined in the same assembly, like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Lib.Resources.Converters">

    <converter:TextSizeConverter x:Key="LabelTextSizeConverter" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize"
                Value="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource LabelTextSizeConverter}}" />
    </Style>

<ResourceDictionary />
```

When I try to load the dictionary in another project I get a `XamlParseException` stating that the `Converter` is of an unknown type.

```
var rd = new ResourceDictionary()
{
    Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Lib.Resources;component/Styles/Label.xaml")
};

Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd);
```

I tried various `BuildActions` for the converter without any success.

Is there a way to fix this, or do I need to approach this in a completely different way?

Comment: did you loook into this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/aa970069.aspx ?

Comment: can you share how you are merging the referenced dictionary?

Comment: @nit: I added some code.

Comment: make sure that buildaction of your resource dictionary is Resource and try doing this in your App.xaml Resources `<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Lib.Resources;component/Styles/Label.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>`

Comment: @nit: I add the dict programmatically to get around a known bug. The buildaction is set to Resource already. Loading the Style is not the issue. It's the "embedded" Converter that's causing problems.

Comment: hmm... can you try giving assembly in xmlns converter `xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Lib.Resources.Converters;assembly=YOUR Assembly"`

Comment: great.. let me add this as answer to help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add the `assembly` in your converter `xmlns`

```
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Lib.Resources.Converters;assembly=YOUR Assembly"
```